# Timer is not getting stop in SAFARI specifically when window is inActive

Tags: javascript, php

I have used a bunch of javascript code to display countdown on my home-page..
Which works absolutely fine in chrome,FF But in Safari it's not working properly...
The actual scenario is...I want to stop timer when window is inActive And Resume from that particular time when window becomes Active()

My code is...

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
            var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
            var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
            var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
            var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
            return {
                'total': t,
                'hours': hours,
                'minutes': minutes,
                'seconds': seconds
            };
        }

        function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
            var clock = document.getElementById(id);
            var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
            var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
            var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
            var isPaused = true;

            vis(function(){
                isPaused = vis() ? true : false;
            });

            function updateClock() {
                var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

                hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
                minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
                secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

                if (t.total <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(timeinterval);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/myurlToUpdateTime',
                        method: 'post',
                        data: {'rewardId': '<?php echo $video->getId(); ?>', 'page_url': '<?php echo $currentPage; ?>'},
                        response: function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#redirect_url').attr("href", "<?php echo $pageUrl; ?>");
                    document.getElementById('redirect_url').click();
                }
            }

            updateClock();
            //var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
            var timeinterval = setInterval(function(){
                if(isPaused) {
                    updateClock();
                } else {
                    //endtime = new Date(Date.parse(new Date(endtime)) + 1000);
                    endtime = new Date(Date.parse(endtime) + 1000);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + <?php echo $video->getCountdown(); ?> * 1000);
        initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

I have tried some of the solution like `window.onBlur` OR `window.onFocus` ... But they are not leading me to the desired output...

Answer (score 0):

Yes..Finally got the solution which works on all browsers(SAFARI,chrome,FF..)

```
//use starttime instead of date function
function getTimeRemaining(endtime, starttime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(starttime);
        var seconds = (t / 1000) % 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        return {
            'total': t,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime, starttime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');
        var isPaused = true;

        vis(function(){
            isPaused = vis() ? true : false;
        });

        //update start time when isPaused() is true
        function updateClock() {
            starttime = new Date(Date.parse(starttime) + 1000);
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime, starttime);
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/targetURL',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {'rewardId': '<?php echo $video->getId(); ?>', 'page_url': '<?php echo $currentPage; ?>'},
                    response: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
                $('#redirect_url').attr("href", "<?php echo $pageUrl; ?>");
                document.getElementById('redirect_url').click();
            }
        }

        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(function(){
            if(isPaused) {
                updateClock();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + <?php echo $video->getCountdown(); ?> * 1000);
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline, new Date());
```

> Note: Here I have used starttime whenever the isPaused() is true and
>   it will update the time whenever the window is active/deactive
>   accordingly